# Square connect API sandbox

Tags: api, square-connect

I'm using the square API sandbox, with sample code that I've downloaded. I've set up square/connect and mashape/unirest-php using composer, and they show in my composer.json file, and the required files are in the vendor folder. I'm getting the "Fatal error: Class 'SquareConnect\Api\TransactionApi' not found in..." error.

Comment: Square recently released a new version of their SDKs and are still working on fixing their sample code.

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The transaction api in Square's sample code was missing a character. 
The line:
$transaction_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionApi(); 
should be:
$transaction_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();

Comment: Thank you @Dave cox